# Swiffy External Text Loading

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash

I have a simple flash activity that loads its text from an external file called QA.txt using the URLLoader function. I wanted to convert this file to html5 using Google Swiffy, which I have done, expect it doesn't seem to be loading the QA.txt file anymore. I believe it says this functionality is supported on their main website, so I'm wondering why it might not be working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swiffy does indeed support URLLoader!

I think your problem is this: if you open up your converted html file in your browser and also open up the developer tools console (try hitting F12), you should see an error message along the lines of:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load .../...myText.txt. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
```

Because you've open up the converted html page by itself, your browser isn't letting the code in that page fetch any other files, because they aren't being treated as coming from the same origin (even though they might well be sitting in the same directory) due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

To get around this, you should access the swiffy html by fetching it through a local web server, something like apache (php) or node (javascript).

(It should also be working normally if you upload it onto the internet.)

Comment: This is exactly the error I was getting and looks to also be the solution! Thanks!

Comment: Hey I tried uploading it to the server and I am still having issues. I made another post here if you had a moment:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448487/swiffy-not-pulling-external-text