# Swiffy Not Pulling External Text

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, flash

I thought I had solved an issue with my Swiffy file when I uploaded it to my server along with the file it dynamically pulls text from, but even on my server no text is pulled from the external file. It only sits there with everything blank.

And the only thing that shows up in the console is:
[trace] TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. runtime.js:187

Here's a link to the file generated by swiffy (only valid for 15 minutes I think):
[Link 1](https://swiffypreviews.googleusercontent.com/view/o/bfe4f322-f7fa-4f0e-9631-fac2d35109f3/CustomizableQuestions_Scene%201.html?clickTAG=https://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/faq.html%23clickTAG)

Here's a link to the runtime.js file: [Link 2](https://www.gstatic.com/swiffy/v5.2/runtime.js).

EDIT:

This is the line where the error is being given in runtime.js:

```
var rk=function(a,b)
{
    a.__swiffy_baseclass=b[I];
    Xa(a,q[vd](b[I]));
    a[I].constructor=a;
   if(b.__swiffy_if)
   {
       var c=new kh;
       c.Be(b.__swiffy_if);
       q[E](a,"__swiffy_if",{value:c})
   }
},
sk=function(a)
{
    q[E](a[I],"__swiffy_nvr",{value:l})
},
tk=function(a)
{
    ba.console&&ba.console.log("[trace] "+a)
},
uk=function(){},
vk=function(a)
{
    tk(a)
},
wk=function(a)
{
    f(a)
};"__proto__"in q||q[E](mi[I],"__proto__",{get:function(){return q[hd](this)}});
var xk=function(a,b,c,d,e,g,k)
{
    this.D=a;
    this.variables=b;
    this.url=c; fb(this,d||"_self");    La(this,e);
    this.Xk=!!g;
    this.Di=!!k;
    this.Wh=m;
    if(this.Xk||this.Di)
         this.Wh=this.fo()
},
yk={0:h,1:"GET",2:"POST"};
M=xk[I];
```

Comment: Can you post a code excerpt? That error is pretty common - there is something you're referencing in your code doesn't exist (yet).

Comment: Sure, I edited my post above to include the line in runtime.js where the crash is apparently occurring. I went through my flash program and didn't see any errors like this popup anywhere though.

Comment: If you'd like a link to my flash .swf file and the text file its pulling from, you can download them here [SpeedyShare Link](http://www.speedyshare.com/DAePQ/swiffyStuff.zip).

Comment: I think the error message is more associated with the AS3 side of the code, rather than how swiffy does the conversion. A really common occurrence of this error is when some some code in your Main() constructor references the stage while it yet hasn't been added to the stage. You can google the error and you'll get a lot of suggested fixes that often work (e.g. add an event listener for ADDED_TO_STAGE and execute the main code in that handler), but this will be pretty hard to debug without looking at your AS3 code. Is it working fine as a regular swf?

Comment: I think I found out where the error is occurring and you are right, it is in my AS3 code. When I compile it to swiffy, for some reason flash.net.URLVARIABLES are not supported which makes my program crash when running. I'm trying to get this to work without URLVARIABLES now but haven't had much luck as of yet.

Comment: Darn, I'm not sure it's possible to load this stuff if URLVARIABLES isn't supported. I guess they do mean the support is REALLY limited.

Comment: Even though it says this in the patch notes: 

Added support for QName, Namespace, Loader, LoaderInfo, Stage, Matrix, Point, Rectangle, Transform, ColorTransform, Vector3D, URLLoader and URLVariables

So now I'm really confused as it says it supports it...

Comment: Just thought I'd mention that I finally figured out how to do it (I ended up rewriting how the program pulled data). Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Haha I didn't really help much, but congrats on getting it working! I hadn't used urlvariables before so I couldn't confirm that they were working with swiffy.